# Is it possible to change properties of a bean (defined for a service) and reload it when the application is running?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, javabeans

I migrated a simple CRUD application developed in Java using OSGi to Grails using Spring. I converted all the REST resources to controllers and HTML pages to GSP views, keeping the rest of the Java code as such.

I have a `DBService` service, which helps connect to the DB and run queries on it, and a `ProcessorService`, which uses `DBService` to perform business operations.

I created beans for these services as follows:

```
beans = {

    dbServiceBean(DBService, "test_db")

    processorServiceBean(ProcessorService,ref("dbServiceBean"))

}
```

Everything is working fine with the above config.

Now, I want the application to be able to process multiple DBs (multi-tenant). I won’t know the name of the DB beforehand, however, so I can’t have a list of `dbServiceBean`s predefined.

Is it possible to rebuild/reload a bean with dynamically obtained values and reload the dependent beans as well when the application is running?

Answer (score 0):

Grails already have the option to use [multiple datasources](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources).

You can change your `DBService` to get a connection from the datasources configured. If you just change it to a Groovy class and put it in `grails-app/service` you will [get transactions and dependency injection by attribute name for free](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html).